# Resizing UIView causes child table UITableView to disappear

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiview, interface-builder

I have a UIView which contains a label, a button, and a UITableView which populates its data dynamically from a server. I am having trouble resizing the parent UIView to fit its content after the content has dynamically populated. For the purpose of demonstrating my issue, I have made the background of the containing UIView blue.

After populating the TableView with data, the UIView's height does not adjust causing the Tableview data to overflow, seen in the diagram below.

[image]

I have set the bottom, leading and trailing space constraints of the TableView to the superview, and top space constraint to the button. The UIView itself has no height constraints set.

I implemented a function to manually recalculate the height of the UIView after populating the content of the TableView. Code for the function below:

```
    func resizeToFitSubviews()
{

    var w: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width,
    h: CGFloat = 0
    for view in subviews {
        if view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height > h { h = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height }
    }
    self.frame.size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)

}
```

This function works. The UIView resizes to what seems to be the right size, but the TableView disappears after doing so:

[image]

Completely lost as to why this occurs. The label and button seem unaffected. I either need to make it so autolayout automatically adjusts the height of the UIView, or make it so that resizing the UIView does not cause the TableView to disappear.

In the View Debugger, the TableView is returning a height of 0 (while the rows are returning 130 as expected given that is what I return in my heightForRowAt function).

Thanks

Comment: Uuuuuuse the Vieeeeew Debuggggerrrrrrrr, Luuuuuuke!

Comment: @matt In the View Debugger, the TableView is completely gone in the 3D visual, but it does exist in the hierarchy, returning a height of 0. But I don't see why it should be returning 0.

Comment: The view debugger tells you why. It lists the constraints that are going into sizing and positioning this view. If you see an exclamation mark, there's a constraint mistake at your end, and the view debugger tells you what it is. — My point is: you have given no information that might allow anyone to help you. But you can help yourself, so you may as well do so.

Comment: Also, your claim "and have applied the correct constraints" is obviously false. If they were correct, you wouldn't have this problem. Again, since you give no actual details, no one can help you. The question as it stands is pointless.

Comment: One more thing: "This function works" No it doesn't. Setting a view's frame when it is under the control of autolayout is illegal (unless you're doing this as _part_ of layout).

Comment: @matt I thought that too - but when my View was not responding to data changes in the table, I wrote it. Anyhow, I have updated with constraints information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't adjust the view frame if you are using Auto Layout.

Make a height constraint and adjust that to your calculated value.

-

Also it might be easier to manually calculate this height.

`height = numberOfRows * heightPerRow`

Comment: I didn't have a height constraint (nor did I think one was necessary given I was always expecting an unknown height based on the content). I was under the impression that auto layout would automatically determine a height based on all the other constraints I set. Thanks for the clarification. Seems rather cumbersome that you need to pragmatically change the height like this. I thought the purpose of TableViews and StackViews was to make this sort of stuff automatic.

My calculation for determining height was more or less same as yours, but I also added height for the label and padding.

Comment: The tableview is also a scrollview so the actual tableview size doesn't change when the cells change. It just adjusts its contentView size to fit all the cells and they scroll inside the tableview.

Comment: I mean in normal use you would set the tableview to be a set size regardless of the number of cells, and then it will manage scrolling automatically in the area you have given it. If you want to do something unusual, like have the parent view grow to fit the tableview contentView, then yeah it gets a bit fiddly.

Comment: Got it - yeah I disabled scroll as the tableview isn't the root view in my case.